# Prevent webpack from touching environment variables?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to get my Node application to read the environment variables at run time.

Basically, I have this in TypeScript:

```
export const environment: EnvIntf = envMap[process.env.NODE_ENV] as EnvIntf;
```

Which gets compiled to:

```
exports.environment = envMap[process.env.NODE_ENV];
```

And then, after webpack, it turns into:

```
exports.environment = envMap[\"qa\"]
```

That "qa" is the value of the environment variable. I'd like it to not touch it and allow JavaScript to get that value at runtime.

Comment: But the front-end isn't going to be able to understand what `process.env.NODE_ENV` means.  Are you expecting the value to be replaced as the bundle is served automatically?

Comment: This isn't for a Browser. This is in Node. Different environments will have different values. Node is setting this value.